# Which contact form plugin passes Outlook junk / spam filters?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I'd like to know which contact form plugin has the best header and email creation so that Outlook does not filter it as junk mail. I'm using jigowatts simple php contact form. I am going to test the AJAX WP plugin version but would like to hear from everyone and what they use to get emails accepted by Outlook.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/) is working well and no emails are getting filtered as junk in outlook

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way of stopping this other than to set up your contact form to prefix the subject e.g.[MySite] and then use a rule to stop it being filtered as junk.